# I don't understand this statement regarding measurement of impedance parameter of a transistor

Tags: transistors, parameters

I was reading about hybrid parameters from the text book 'Engineering circuit analysis by Hayt-8th edition'. I read a paragraph saying :-

*" The difficulty in measuring quantities such as the open-circuit impedance
parameters arises when a parameter such as **z**<sub>21</sub> must be measured. A known
sinusoidal current is easily supplied at the input terminals, but because of
the exceedingly high output impedance of the transistor circuit, it is difficult
to open-circuit the output terminals and yet supply the necessary dc biasing
voltages and measure the sinusoidal output voltage. A short-circuit current
measurement at the output terminals is much simpler to implement. "*

Here, I don't understand the statement ***" because of
the exceedingly high output impedance of the transistor circuit, it is difficult
to open-circuit the output terminals and yet supply the necessary dc biasing
voltages and measure the sinusoidal output voltage."*** Can anybody clarify what they are implying?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's not saying it's hard to open-circuit the output terminal of the transistor. But if you do, it's not easy to keep the transistor biased in active mode.

Comment: What about this part -> " because of the exceedingly high output impedance of the transistor circuit "

Comment: Consider the structure of a bias tee. What about it would complicate the measurement of a high impedance?

Comment: @LelouchYagami. In order for your connected "open circuit" to be an effective open circuit it must have much higher impedance than the device you're trying to measure. The high impedance of the transistor circuit's output makes it harder to achieve that.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bias the transistor, a particular dc collector-emitter voltage must be applied. ( for example, 10V). However, for ac signals, the collector and  emitter terminals should be open-circuited. So, at dc, a low impedance constant voltage is needed, while for ac signals, a high impedance must be presented to the terminals.

One solution to this would be to connect the collector and emitter to a very large inductor, and then the inductor to a dc power supply.  However, it is extremely difficult to make ideal inductors.

Other circuit techniques could be used, but it is difficult to make a high impedance for ac signals with a constant dc bias.

It is easy to make a low impedance at ac with a dc bias, a good power supply does this.  Thus, for transistors, it is easier to measure y parameters or some hybrid parameters than z parameters.

Comment: I guess, it will take some more studying for me to understand this.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks.